# How does the default MVC4 account security work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-4

If you create MVC4 application with its default template on VS2012, you get a pre built account and security model controller and view.

I would like to know where the actual password salt and comparing take place, is it within the Account controller or Initialize membership attribute?

[image]
[image]

Also can someone explain how the websecurity object works?

I've tried looking up Microsoft's documents online about it but got no further than what i know now.

Comment: Why are you creating a new `MVC4` project? I recommend to use `MVC5`, especially because it uses `ASP.NET Identity` which is also open source...

Comment: @ChrFin i have already completed the MVC4 project, i have to explain in my report how my application will work, hence this question. I just wanted to use the new MVC4 project as a reference for you guys to see what i am asking for

Comment: Report for school or work? Either way I suspect you can blag the fact that it's a Microsoft framework for authorisation and you probably aren't actually expected to explain the entire inner mechanism for something like that. You could well be overcomplicating :)

Comment: Report for school, it all works of course but i need to explain in my implementation section how the security of my web app works, would be rather short just explaining " Microsoft handles it" hahaha

Comment: I'm sure there is plenty of stuff on the web relating to this

Comment: Lol, explain in moderation then. Here's a few references: [ref](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates) [ref2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/689801/Understanding-and-Using-Simple-Membership-Provider) [ref3](http://brockallen.com/2012/09/02/think-twice-about-using-membershipprovider-and-simplemembership/)

Comment: @Sippy Thanks! ill take a look at these and see if it adds anymore to what i know now. i appreciate it